# Error while rotating bitmapdata

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, bitmapdata, image-rotation

While trying to rotate a bitmap Image, I am finding some unwanted design patterns on the rotated image. I have used Matrix for rotation.

Comment: You are going to need to provide more information if you want help.  There currently doesn't seem to be a question here.

Comment: Since i can't attach an image here, i am finding it difficult to put it in words.

Comment: I am trying to read a jpg image into a bitmap data(in which i was successful) and cut a part of it (diagonally). After that rotating the clipped image to make it vertical, which i am able to do. But the resulting image have some missing pixels which ultimately looks like a deisgn

Comment: @Rahul TP I think you should be able to link to an image.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your getting Bitmap rotation artifacts from your comments. Try setting your Bitmap smoothing property to true and see if that helps. I've also seen people that change the "z" property on Bitmap to something like "1" which turns on the Flash10 3D stage transforms which improves smoothing a tab (at a cost of performance).

Comment: please find the picture in this link. http://i41.tinypic.com/2ib1c9u.png I am getting some noise in the rotated image